# Which episode of “X-Men: The Animated Series” shows Lilandra hitting a control panel?

Tags: marvel, x-men, episode-identification, x-men-97, x-men-the-animated-series

In the opening sequence of *X-Men '97*, Season 1, Episode 3, "Fire Made Flesh", there's a brief clip showing Lilandra aggressively hitting a control panel while Araki and a shocked Professor X look on. This clip appears to be from (or based on) a scene in the *X-Men '97* prequel, *X-Men: The Animated Series*.

[image: the scene described above]

Could anyone identify the episode from *X-Men: The Animated Series* that features this scene?

Comment: Prof X doesn't look like the classic series to me. And assuming the new series is HD it's probably easier to just animate a pastiche flashback than splice something in.  But I don't know maybe the series does have prior examples of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this site](https://decider.com/2024/03/27/x-men-97-episode-3-easter-eggs-fire-made-flesh/), it's a redraw of a scene in 3×17, "The Dark Phoenix Part IV: The Fate of the Phoenix".

[image: Image of Lilandra striking a panel]